# how to manage my website design through css

Tags: asp.net

i want to manage all the design of my website(asp.net) through my css.
my client requirement is he should be able to change all design of website within 4-5 hrs.
is this possible.
is there any trick to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Sure it is. ASP.NET doesn't but render html, css and javascript. What you need it to let it render the html you're after and hook in css for layouting.

ASP.NET also provides you with some great functionality: Themes and skins. These make changing css, images, ... a snap by either configuration or setting a certain premaid theme in code. I suggest you take a look at these videos for more information:

- [Customize my Site with Profiles and Themes?](http://www.asp.net/general/videos/how-do-i-customize-my-site-with-profiles-and-themes)
- [Create User Selectable Themes for a Web Site](http://www.asp.net/general/videos/how-do-i-create-user-selectable-themes-for-a-web-site)
- [Use Skins with CSS for a Flexible and Maintainable ASP.NET Web Site](http://www.asp.net/general/videos/how-do-i-use-skins-with-css-for-a-flexible-and-maintainable-aspnet-web-site)

Answer (score 0):

That's a very tall order indeed. By design does the client mean the color/theme or also the layout?

Basically is boils down to the following:
1. Generate semantic html only from you ASP.NET code. That is no in-line style and use meaning full css class names for html that needs to be styled
2. Break your css files into two. One for style and layout and another for color. If you're using images, they should be a part of your color css file

You can start here but also be clear about what your client means by "should be able to change the design within 4-5 hours".

Answer (score 0):

Yes this possible if you have good knowledge of CSS i.e. 2 and 3. Have look at below links which can provide you and idea about layouts fully dependent on CSS

> [Yui library](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/)
>
> [Yui CSS tools](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/)

Many more ideas like CSS sprite can be used to achieve what you need